# How to crop image from url and set to wallpaper

Tags: android, image, url, crop, android-glide

I want to crop the image I'm getting from the URL using Glide and set as the devise wallpaper

I tried so many libraries but it does not work as I need.

I tried the below link which crops the image from the storage but I want to crop the image from the URL using glide.

https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop